# How to train millions of doc2vec embeddings using GPU?

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, word-embeddings

I am trying to train a doc2vec based on user browsing history (urls tagged to user_id). I use chainer deep learning framework.

There are more than 20 millions (user_id and urls) of embeddings to initialize which doesn’t fit in a GPU internal memory (maximum available 12 GB). Training on CPU is very slow.

I am giving an attempt using code written in chainer given [here](https://github.com/monthly-hack/chainer-doc2vec)

Please advise options to try if any.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to switch to a deep learning framework that supports distributed training.